# How can i return the InsertedId from mongoDB document after insertion. Tried InsertedId but it returns null

Tags: mongodb, kotlin

Am using ktor and MongoDB as my backend for an android project. When inserting a document, the acknowledgment returns true, but when I get InsertedId, it returns null despite being inserted in the database.I need the inserted id so that I can store it in session and also return the inserted object with the id to android. Am new to MongoDB and could be doing something wrong.

**Here is my POJO class in ktor**

```
@Serializable
data class User(
    @BsonId
    val _id: String? = ObjectId.get().toString(),
    val username: String,
    val password: String,
    val salt: String

)
```

**Here is my repositoryImpl**

```
class MongoUserDataSource(
    db: CoroutineDatabase
): UserDataSource {

    private val users = db.getCollection<User>()

    override suspend fun getUserByUsername(username: String): User? {
        return users.findOne(User::username eq username)
    }

    override suspend fun insertUser(user: User): BsonValue? {
        return users.insertOne(user).insertedId
    }

    override suspend fun getUser(userId: String): User? {
       return users.findOneById(userId)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do your `findById`, I believe you want to search using an `ObjectId` instead of the string value.  I would update your `insertUser` function as so

```
override suspend fun insertUser(user: User): ObjectId? {
    return users.insertOne(user).insertedId.asObjectId().value
}
```

and `getUser` like this

```
override suspend fun getUser(userId: ObjectId): User? {
    return users.findOneById(userId)
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I don't remember trying this but I did a work_around by inserting the doc and retrieving it using a unique identifier once the acknowledgment is made.